# which one uses connection pools? django.core.cache vs django_redis.get_redis_connection (when using django-redis)

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, django-redis

There are 2 methods to get the redis connection when using django-redis (https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/) lib

**method-1**

```
from django.core.cache import caches
# get redis cache from settings
rcache = caches['redis']
```

**method-2**

```
from django_redis import get_redis_connection
rcache = get_redis_connection("redis")
```

my django settings look like this

```
CACHES = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache",
            "LOCATION": MEMCACHED_URL,
            "OPTIONS": {
                'MAX_ENTRIES': 2000
            }
        },
        "redis": {
            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
            "LOCATION": REDIS_URL,
            "OPTIONS": {
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried checking internals and looks like get_redis_connection uses a connection pool, but the object it returns is of the strictredis client and not the default client - hence one cannot exactly jump from one to another.

That being said, can someone confirm which one to use if you want to use connection pool when using the ***django-redis*** library

Note: I am using memcache as the default django cache backend at present, with redis for some other caching purposes.

Please let me know if the question or description sounds confusing, i can update.

Comment: Both methods rely on redis-py and redis-py is always using a connection pool.

Comment: Hi Maurice, I just double-checked and you are right. I'll be happy to accept your answer.